Safe to store public key encrypted private key?
I am implementing an anonymous credential system following Lysyanskaya, 2002, specifically much of chapter 3. We assume that the user (not anonymous) has a user public key $PK_U$ and user private key, $SK_U$. When creating the pseudonym this user creates a key pair $(PK_N,SK_N)$, but will not store these credentials.
If I want to allow this user to authenticate as some pseudonym $N$, my thinking is the server (organization $O$ in the thesis) stores the pseudonym $N$, the pseudonym public key $PK_N$ and the pseudonym private key, but encrypted with the user public key, that is $E_{PK_U}(SK_N)$. This way if the user really is who they claim to be, then $O$ can encrypt some random message $m$ with the pseudonym public key, provide the user only with the encrypted message $E_{PK_N}(m)$ and the encrypted private key $E_{PK_U}(SK_N)$. If the user can then return to $O$ the original message $m$, I will know that they have the private key $SK_U$ and thus are authenticated as this pseudonym.
I would be storing the following tuples in the database (in two separate tables).
$(U,PK_U)$
$(N,PK_N,E_{PK_U}(SK_N))$
Is this safe to store in the database?
I don't plan on exactly broadcasting this value, but say if there was a data breach, would it still be safe and not risk de-anonymizing the user?
It’s worth adding that I have since asked this question to ChatGPT and it said that we must always assume that $PK_U$ is public and even if someone could not decrypt $E_{PK_U}(SK_N)$, they could tell that $PK_U$ was used to encrypt it, thus de-anonymizing the user U. It suggested using a key derivation function instead to service $SK_N$.

If you have lost access to your account or if you want to merge them then please contact SE / the CM team (contact button at the bottom).

please give a full reference to Lysanskaya 2002

"Is it safe" will depend on your threat model and security goals, so it's hard to say without them. For example, in what you've described, the server can only produce the database entry by interacting with the user to receive PK$_U$ in order to encrypt SK$_N$. Why not simply have the server give SK$_N$ to the user at this point? And why wouldn't the server just record this interaction, to connect N to U?
Maybe you do trust the server, but want to model a threat where the server is compromised at some point, and want everything in the database at that time to be anonymous. Or more precisely, that given a tuple for a pseudonym $N$ that either belongs to a user $U_1$ or $U_2$, no adversary should be able to distinguish which user it belongs to. This is basically key privacy, which does not hold for all public key encryption schemes.
In any case, I recommend being very careful about the security notions you want. Formalizing them in the style of typical security definitions can be very helpful.
